# CSS Fluid Title

Tags: html, css

I need to make a title fluid in a  page template for a CMS I have built the code I have is below.

```
<div class="content-output-title-container" id="page-title">
    <h1 class="content-output-title">{page_name}</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-output-title-container {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 0!important;
    padding-top: 42px;
    z-index: 4!important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

.content-output-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 280px;
    border-left-width: 20px;
    border-left-color: #00AFA9;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 20000px;
    border-right-color: #64405F;
    border-right-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see I have a border on both edges which needs to persist for any length of title text.

The issue is that when the title text is something like

[image]

the border behaves and the title is full width in the container however if the title is something like

[image]

Is there a way in CSS that I can make the longer title flow and not wrap with the borders present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want the second example to continue along one line (only wrapping when it gets to 100% width of the page) then you can do this by using the `:after` pseudo element:

```css
.content-output-title-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-output-title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-left-width: 20px;
  border-left-color: #00AFA9;
  border-left-style: solid;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content-output-title:after {
  display:block;
  content: " ";
  background-color: #64405F;
  width: 2000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-output-title-container" id="page-title">
    <h1 class="content-output-title">{page name}</h1>
</div>

<div class="content-output-title-container" id="page-title">
    <h1 class="content-output-title">{extra long page name}</h1>
</div>

<div class="content-output-title-container" id="page-title">
    <h1 class="content-output-title">{extra extra long page name}</h1>
</div>

<div class="content-output-title-container" id="page-title">
    <h1 class="content-output-title">{extra extra extra long page name}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy that is awesome! +1 and answer awarded